# Is it possible to write this in an ARRAYFORMULA?

Tags: google-sheets

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT("A" & MATCH(G2, A:A,0)))+1,COLUMN(A:A)))`

Instead of having to drag down the cells, is it possible write this to support ARRAYFORMULA?

`=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT("A" & MATCH(G2:G, A:A,0)))+1,COLUMN(A:A))))`

Attempting it to write it like this returns:

> Did not find value '' in MATCH evaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Here's one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E_tX96Yxc0P3Dr9fIWUwMCEkLsuounyrfHEOx43P8-0/edit#gid=1668799294) you may test out:*

```js
=map(F:F,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,ifna(index(A:A,xmatch(Σ,A:A)+1)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Write the formula to support ARRAYFORMULA, you can use the INDEX function instead of INDIRECT. Here's an example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(A:A, MATCH(G2:G, A:A, 0) + 1))
```

Formula will return an array of values from column A, starting from the row after the match for each corresponding value in column G. Make sure to adjust the range A:A to match the actual range you want to reference.

Comment: Wow. Looks much more elegant. I went ahead and tried, but for some reason, it only returns one result. Did I do something wrong? Feel free to take a look [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E_tX96Yxc0P3Dr9fIWUwMCEkLsuounyrfHEOx43P8-0/edit#gid=2026429662&range=G3) if you want.