# Increase rows based on a condition in LAMBDA MAP?

Tags: google-sheets

Asked [Is it possible to write this in an ARRAYFORMULA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77593459/is-it-possible-to-write-this-in-an-arrayformula) last week that got resolved. However, I got a new problem and still did not manage to find a solution, so trying here again.

Here is the newest variant of my older code:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT("A" & MATCH(F1, A:A, 0)))+1, COLUMN(A:A))) = "NO MORE STATUSES.", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT("A" & MATCH(F1, A:A, 0)))+16, COLUMN(A:A))), INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(INDIRECT("A" & MATCH(F1, A:A, 0)))+1, COLUMN(A:A)))))
```

With this, I could increase by 16 rows instead of by 1 row based on a certain condition.

Is it possible to achieve the same with what rockinfreakshow helped with in my last post?

```
=MAP(F:F, LAMBDA(Σ, IF(Σ = "", , IFNA(INDEX(A:A, XMATCH(Σ, A:A)+1)))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(F:F,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,let(Λ,ifna(index(A:A,xmatch(Σ,A:A)+1)),if(Λ="NO MORE STATUSES.",ifna(index(A:A,xmatch(Σ,A:A)+16)),Λ)))))
```

Comment: Oh... It worked! Thank you so much! 